# Convolution of two indicator functions

Tags: convolution, indicator-function

I am experiencing difficulties understanding the concept of convolution and especially convolution of 2 independent indicator functions. I would be really thankful if someone can help understand the intuition behind it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: X1 and X2 are 2 i.i.d. random variables with probability density function
 fx=1 for x[0,1]
      0 elsewise
Find the density function of Y=X1+X2